# Form CSS input:hover and input:focus not working in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, focus, hover

I'm using CSS styling of input:hover and input:focus on this page:

[Lenticular Printing and 3D Promotional Products](http://www.lenticularpromo.com/3D-Lenticular-Printing-and-Promotional-Product-Sample-Reque-s/368.htm)

The effects work in Chrome and Firefox, but not IE. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

If you are not seeing the focus color charging on your local machine (or an Intranet site) when using IE9, use `Tools >> Compatibility View Settings`, and disable the `Compatability` checkboxes.

This will override the setting on a browser-level, irregardless of the site's code.

Answer (score 2):

[`:focus`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-focus) is not supported in < IE8.

Answer (score 2):

Check that the html document is valid because Internet explorer could be in quirks mode, to do this be sure that your document is valid, and check the html document headers:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

Comment: The page had no doctype! Good catch.

Comment: The page does indeed have no doctype, but when I add one, the page displays with a bunch of grey bars in IE9. Perhaps this is a problem with Volusion's code?

Comment: grey bars? sounds like an: "IE-breaking-the-CSS-rules" related stuff.